# How to map a surround command?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to map commands that are used with the [vim surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin. Using vim surround you can type `ysiW]`, for example, while in normal mode and it will surround the word at the cursor with brackets. I tried doing `nonoremap ;y ysiW]` but it doesn't work (nothing happens).

```
" These work for other things
nnoremap ;li :Limelight!!<CR>
nnoremap ;ww g<C-g>
" Below doesn't work
nnoremap ;y ysiW]
```

Is there a reason it won't work using this syntax?

Comment: I can't test it right now but it's probably because vim waits for more input as your mapping shadows the `y` command. Does it happen with another mapping, like `<leader>y`?

Comment: With <leader> it does look like it's waiting for something. But I don't think y itself is the problem, because if I change it to another key it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the rare times you need `:nmap`—you need the `ys` map to be expanded, too, which is recursive:

```
nmap ;y ysiW]
```